# Oracle SQL query help getting all the columns of a list of tables in tabular format

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am trying to get list of all column-names associated with different tables in a tabular format.

Thank you in advance for your help.

The query I have is:

```sql
select table_name , COLUMN_NAME
from all_tab_columns 
where column_name in ('COLUMN_1','COLUMN_2','COLUMN_3','COLUMN_4') 
group by table_name, column_name;
```

---

What I would like to see is:

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table_a | Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 |
| Table_b | Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 |
| Table_c | Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 |

Answer (score 0):

That looks like some kind of pivoting.

Sample tables whose columns you'd like to see:

```
SQL> select * from emp where rownum = 1;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20

SQL> select * from dept where rownum = 1;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
```

Query itself:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (select table_name, column_name, column_id
  3        from user_Tab_columns
  4        where table_name in ('DEPT', 'EMP')
  5       )
  6  pivot
  7  (max(column_name)
  8   for column_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
  9  )
 10  order by table_name;

TABLE_NAME 1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9          10
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
DEPT       DEPTNO     DNAME      LOC
EMP        EMPNO      ENAME      JOB        MGR        HIREDATE   SAL        COMM       DEPTNO

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
         SELECT table_name , COLUMN_NAME
         FROM   all_tab_columns 
         WHERE  column_name in ('COLUMN_1','COLUMN_2','COLUMN_3','COLUMN_4')
       )
       PIVOT (
         MAX(column_name) FOR column_name IN (
           'COLUMN_1' AS column_name_1,
           'COLUMN_2' AS column_name_2,
           'COLUMN_3' AS column_name_3,
           'COLUMN_4' AS column_name_4
         )
       );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (Column_1, Column_2, Column_3, Column_4 ) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_2 (Column_1, Column_2, Column_3, Column_4 ) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_3 (Column_4, Column_3, Column_2, Column_1 ) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME_1 | COLUMN_NAME_2 | COLUMN_NAME_3 | COLUMN_NAME_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TABLE_1 | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 | COLUMN_4 |
| TABLE_2 | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 | COLUMN_4 |
| TABLE_3 | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 | COLUMN_4 |

---

Alternatively if you want the first 4 columns (in the order they occur in the table) for all tables that that contain at least one of those columns then you can use:

```sql
SELECT owner,
       table_name,
       column_name_1,
       column_name_2,
       column_name_3,
       column_name_4
FROM   (
         SELECT owner,
                table_name,
                COLUMN_NAME,
                column_id,
                COUNT(
                  CASE
                  WHEN column_name in ('COLUMN_1','COLUMN_2','COLUMN_3','COLUMN_4')
                  THEN 1
                  END
                ) OVER (PARTITION BY owner, table_name) AS has_matches
         FROM   all_tab_columns
       )
       PIVOT (
         MAX(column_name) FOR column_id IN (
           1 AS column_name_1,
           2 AS column_name_2,
           3 AS column_name_3,
           4 AS column_name_4
         )
       )
WHERE  has_matches > 0;
```

Outputs:

| OWNER | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME_1 | COLUMN_NAME_2 | COLUMN_NAME_3 | COLUMN_NAME_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FIDDLE_MGOBEHWSSMRSDSPNPYSW | TABLE_1 | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 | COLUMN_4 |
| FIDDLE_MGOBEHWSSMRSDSPNPYSW | TABLE_2 | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 | COLUMN_4 |
| FIDDLE_MGOBEHWSSMRSDSPNPYSW | TABLE_3 | COLUMN_4 | COLUMN_3 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R3VPr3GC)